# Learning Django, but confused with variables

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am going through the Django Tutorial and i am on step 3 of creating polls app. There is a variable called "question_id" and i cant understand where exactly this is defined or where its coming from. I will post the files bellow. My only guess is that this variable is somehow created by Django internally when class Question is defined in Models.py, but i am not sure. Its not defined in "Question" class.

Here are my files:

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader

from .models import Question


def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    context = {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list}
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)


#def index(request):
#    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")

def detail(request, question_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're looking at question %s." % question_id)

def results(request, question_id):
    response = "Your looking at result of question %s."
    return HttpResponse(response % question_id)

def vote(reqeust, question_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're voting on question %s." % question_id)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    #ex: /polls/
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    #ex: /polls/5
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+/$)', views.detail, name='detail'),
    #ex: /polls/5/result/
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+/results/$)', views.results, name='results'),
    #ex: /polls/5/vote
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+/vote/$)', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

models.py

```
import datetime

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)



class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

Thank you for your help,
Nermin

Comment: According to the Django Tutorial (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial03/) I assume you are looking at, those are parameters for the HTTP request. The URLs are passed in via urls.py, and the params are pieces of the URL provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question_id in the three views that are shown are automatically created  by django. It takes the url as input for this purpose. It's defined here

```
url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+/$)', views.detail, name='detail'),
```

Thus if you type in `polls/somenumber/` into the browser your view named `detail` get's passed a variable named as `question_id` and a value of `somenumber`

The regular expression used in urls.py ensures that this is a number and not something else.

For more information refer: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/

Comment: Thank you that was my thought but i was not certain.

Comment: Great thank you for the heads up and ill make sure to up vote as soon as i have enough reputation. :)

Comment: don't worry too much about it. There's one from me to your question to get you on your way

Answer (score 0):

That is a parameter in your functions in `views.py`, and the format of URLs as specified in `urls.py`.

Answer (score 0):

question_id is just the name assigned to the primary key in the database record. Hope this helped :)

Answer (score 0):

When you have a model in Django with no other ForeignKey variables defined the framework will automatically generate an id field that acts as a unique identifier for those objects.

In the case of the tutorial question is defined as:

```
class Question(models.Model):
question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

def __str__(self):
    return self.question_text

def was_published_recently(self):
    return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Behind the covers Django is adding a hidden ID field that looks something like:

```
id = models.ForeignKey(Integer)
```

Each Question object you create will have a unique incremented id associated with it (take a look through the admin portal).

To more specifically answer your question, question_id is being passed down from the view. If you look more through the tutorials they change question_id to instead read as pk (primary key).

The url http://127.0.0.1/question/polls/4 will call detail(request, question_id). In this case it is litterally just passing the value of 4 to the function and then returning that id in the HttpResponse. Later in the tutorial you will instead be returning the Question object with id 4.

This bit here basically says pass on a variable called question_id that looks like a number.
    (?P[0-9]+/$)

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense, so i guess i was not to far of from assuming that Django infect did generate "question_id" upon creation of the Question class. Its good to know if the foreignkey is not defined within the class that Django will generate one for you. That said do you know if for example the naming is the same ex. If i write a class "Author" in models.py and i do not define foreignkey in "Author" class, that Django will name it "author_id" ?

Comment: Not quite. Django will create a field called "id".  The reason that it was question_id in this case is actually because of your urls.py. You defined the variable name when you coded <question_id>.

Comment: Got it, Thank you!